# Updating the column cell of a Table with combo viewer selected data JFace

Tags: java, swt, jface

I Have a table with 4 columns. ReferenceID,Question,Category and Reviewed.
RefrenceId,Question Category are normal texts while Reviewed is a drop down with yes or blank value.

RefrenceId, Question,Category gets the value from a model object called QuestionType.

For reviewed it is always fixed value Yes , Blank not from the model object.

I have created the Tabel viewer, Created columns , Have added different cell editors, also editing support for review column.

Till now data is coming for all the column. But when I select the reviewed column with any selection, value is not appearing in the selected cell

Below is my code

```
private void createCheckListTableUI(Composite parent) {
checkListTableViewer = new TableViewer(tableContainer, SWT.RESIZE | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.SINGLE);
    checkListTableViewer.setContentProvider(new ObservableSetContentProvider());
    checkListTableViewer.getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);
    checkListTableViewer.getTable().setLinesVisible(true);
    TableColumnLayout tcl = new TableColumnLayout();
    createColumnsForCheckListTable(checkListTableViewer, tcl);
    CellEditor[] editors = new CellEditor[4];
    editors[0] = new TextCellEditor(checkListTableViewer.getTable());
    editors[1] = new TextCellEditor(checkListTableViewer.getTable());
    editors[2] = new TextCellEditor(checkListTableViewer.getTable());        
    editors[3] = new ComboBoxCellEditor(parent, reviewed, SWT.DROP_DOWN);        
    checkListTableViewer.setCellEditors(editors);
    checkListTableViewer.setInput(checkListModel.getAvailableQuestList());
    tableContainer.setLayoutData(GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).align(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL).span(3, 30).create());
    tableContainer.setLayout(tcl);
}
```

Column creation Code

```
private void createColumnsForCheckListTable(TableViewer checkListTableViewer, TableColumnLayout tcl) {
  //RefID
    TableViewerColumn refIdColumn = createColumn(checkListTableViewer, Constants.CHECKLIST_REFID, 80);
    tcl.setColumnData(refIdColumn.getColumn(), new ColumnWeightData(80));
    refIdColumn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            if (element instanceof QuestionType) {
                QuestionType question = (QuestionType) element;
                return question.getRefID();
            }
            return element.toString();
        }
    });
   ...

TableViewerColumn reviewedColumn = createColumn(checkListTableViewer, Constants.CHECKLIST_REVIEWED, 80);
    ReviewColumnEditorSupport revColEditing = new ReviewColumnEditorSupport(reviewedColumn.getViewer(),checkListModel.getReviewedVal());
    reviewedColumn.setEditingSupport(revColEditing);
    tcl.setColumnData(reviewedColumn.getColumn(), new ColumnWeightData(90));
    reviewedColumn.setLabelProvider(new CellLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
            if(cell.getElement() instanceof String) {
                cell.setText(((String) cell.getElement()));
            }
        }
    });
```

}

Editing Support class look like below

```
public final class ReviewColumnEditorSupport  extends EditingSupport {
    private String[] reviewed = {"","yes","No"};
    private ComboBoxViewerCellEditor cellEditor = null;
    private WritableValue isReviewedValue;

    public ReviewColumnEditorSupport(ColumnViewer viewer, WritableValue isReviewedValue) {
        super(viewer);
        this.isReviewedValue = isReviewedValue;
        cellEditor = new ComboBoxViewerCellEditor((Composite) getViewer().getControl(), SWT.READ_ONLY);
        cellEditor.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider());
        cellEditor.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
        cellEditor.setInput(reviewed);
        cellEditor.addListener(new ICellEditorListener() {

            @Override
            public void editorValueChanged(boolean oldValidState, boolean newValidState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void cancelEditor() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void applyEditorValue() {
                CCombo combo =  (CCombo) cellEditor.getControl();
                isReviewedValue.setValue(combo.getText());
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element) {
        return cellEditor;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean canEdit(Object element) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getValue(Object element) {

        if (element instanceof QuestionType) {
            CCombo combo =  (CCombo) cellEditor.getControl();
            return combo.getText();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setValue(Object element, Object value) {
        if (element instanceof QuestionType && value instanceof String) {
          //  CCombo combo =  (CCombo) cellEditor.getControl();
            getViewer().update(value, null);
            isReviewedValue.setValue((String)value);

        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me in understanding what is going wrong. 
Since data fro reviewed column is not coming from model should there be special handling for this?

A sample code snippet is also fine.

Comment: Are you sure `isReviewedValue` is modified with the value you selected in the combo ?

Comment: Yes. I debugged and value is being updated.

Comment: Try returning `isReviewedValue.getValue()` in your `getValue()` inside the editing support

Comment: See the answer. If any clarificatios required. Comment me back.

Answer (score 0):

getValue() and setValue() for combo should use integer value instead of string. Return index of value in string array from getValue() method, and in setValue() set the index of value. Probably you will be getting an int value there from 'value'. Try to debug.
if its string value then find the index of value in array. and

isReviewedValue.select(index);